# Cloud Firestore/ Flutter - Map sorted by Database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I simply upload a Map with the index values from A1 to A10, the List ist sorted like that:

A1, A10, A2, A3....

When I upload that List, it is sorted correctly (A1.A2..A10) but in Firebase it is resorted like I explained.

```
void updateList(newList) async {
  try {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("centers")
        .document(localUser.centerId)
        .updateData({
      "list": newList,
    });
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

So how can I stop this auto-sort behaviour, I dont want to re-sort the list after getting it from Firebase.flutter

Comment: Instead of explaning provide the response and required response

Answer (score 0):

What [data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) are you uploading exactly? A Map or an Array?

If you upload an Array the elements will maintain the position assigned to them.

If you upload a Map the elements will be sorted based on both the key and the value.

Based on the behavior you are describing, it looks like you are uploading a Map but expecting to download an Array. Regardless, if you are working with a Map you shouldn't care about the order since you will be accessing the values by key, is there any particular reason you would like to have a *sorted* dictionary?

To sum up, this is an expected behavior on Maps, you can read more about this [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).